# Mapbox react - Display route with adjustments to nearest road using list of location points

Tags: reactjs, mapbox, mapbox-gl, react-map-gl

I'm using mapbox with the wrapper react-map-gl.
I'm trying to draw a route with my array of lat lang points,
I found a partial solution from:
https://github.com/visgl/react-map-gl/issues/591#issuecomment-454307294

[image]

The issue is that the presented route doesn't match the nearest road.

The current route is the green line and I'm trying to change it to be like the orange line

Comment: Do you have a code snippet of your code that you could provide for us? Without one we can only make guesses at what is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution I have found is to use the react-map-gl with the deck.gl libraries.

[decl.gl](https://deck.gl/),
[react-map-gl](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/)

1. install the libraries
2. Create a function using the Matching API from Mapbox:
   https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/get-started-map-matching-api/#add-the-map-matching-api
   Use the geometries=geojson option param (inside the URL of the matching call)
3. return the geometry object from Matching API response (data.matchings[0].geometry)
4. Create GeoJsonLayer with the new geometry object:

   ```
   const layerRoute = new GeoJsonLayer({
    id: "geojson-layer",
    data: getMatchingGeometry(),
    filled: true,
    stroked: false,
    extruded: true,
    pickable: true,
    lineJointRounded: true,
    getRadius: 50,
    getElevation: 30,
    lineWidthScale: 20,})
   ```
5. Add the new layer to your map:

   ```
     return (
      <DeckGL layers={[layerRoute]} initialViewState={{ ...initialView }} controller={true}>
        <StaticMap
          height={height}
          width={width}
          mapStyle={mapboxstyle}
          mapboxApiAccessToken={API_TOKEN}
        />
      </DeckGL>)
   ```

Comment: `import ReactGL from 'react-map-gl' `.. is this work insted of `DeskGL`